# How can i remove " sdl2 - ImportError" and "pil - ModuleNotFoundError" from my kivy program

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

I am new to kivy , want to run my very first program but i am getting

```
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed " and "pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

what should i do to eliminate the error?

i tried  installing all:

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew

python -m pip install kivy.deps.sdl2
```

but nothing seems to resolve my issue.

this is my code i tried:

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Myapp(App):
    def  build(self):
        return Label(text="Abhay 's APP")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Myapp().run()
```

OUTPUT I Got:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\SONY VAIO\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-05-05_44.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\SONY VAIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\SONY VAIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
  File "C:\Users\SONY VAIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\SONY VAIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

Comment: Have you exactly followed these instructions? https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installationwindows.html . Did any error occur while you tried to install them?

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo in the link. It must be https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

When using pycharm, you need to install all the dependencies in the pycharm environment.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Apparently there's no Python 3.5+ support with pypi.

Instead, try installing it from the master branch on github:

```
python -m pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
```

Make sure to install pygame as well:

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

Found this solution on their github:
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4991